# Dimension and base change

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, schemes

This is part (f) of Hartshorne, Chapter 2 - Exercise 3.20. I've managed to prove the other parts but stuck on this one.

> Suppose $ X $ is an integral scheme of finite type over a field $ k $ (not assumed algebraically closed). If $ k'/k $ is any extension, then show that every irreducible component of $ X' = X \times_{k} k' $ has dimension equal to $ \dim X $.

My try (I don't even know if this is correct): Let $ Z $ be an irreducible component of $ X' $. Since the dimension depends only on the underlying topological space, we may assume that $ Z $ has the reduced subscheme structure, so that $ Z $ is integral. Then by some previous exercises, $ Z $ is an integral scheme of finite type over $ k' $.

If $ X $ is covered by open affines $ U_i = \text{Spec} A_i $, $ i = 1, \cdots, n $, then $ X' $ is covered by $ V_i = \text{Spec} (A_i \otimes_{k} k') $. Assuming $ Z \cap V_1 \neq \emptyset $, by part (e), $ \dim Z = \dim (Z \cap V_1) $. Now $ Z \cap V_1 $ is a closed integral subscheme of $ V_1 $, so $ Z \cap V_1 = \text{Spec} (A_1 \otimes_{k} k'/Q) $ for some prime ideal $ Q $ of $ A_1 \otimes_{k} k' $. I'm stuck at this point because I have no idea how to compute the dimension of that ring.

The [question has been asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634233/dimension-of-scheme-of-finite-type-over-a-field-under-base-change-hartshorne-ex), but I don't really follow the line of arguments there.

Comment: The answer in the linked question seems like a nice way to solve this problem - are you looking for help in understanding what's going on there, or are you looking for different approaches? If it's the first, could you be more precise about where your difficulties with that argument are?

Comment: I stupidly forgot the fact that $ \dim X = \sup \dim U_{\alpha} $ for any open cover $ U_{\alpha} $, but then why does *every* irreducible component have dimension equal to $ \dim X $ there?

Comment: To add more details: It is clear that $ \dim X' = \dim X $. The dimension of $ X' $ is the supremum of dimensions of its irreducible components (which are finitely many as $ X' $ is noetherian). So there is an irreducible component which has dimension $ = \dim X $. I don't see why all of them have the same dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume $X$ is affine is possible because we can just run the proof on each affine open of $X$. So fix $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$, and fix an embedding $X\hookrightarrow \Bbb A^n_k$, which is equivalent to choosing generators $R:=k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to A$, exhibiting $A$ as $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/I$ for some prime ideal $I$. (We know $I$ is prime by the assumption that $X$ is integral.)

In the case that $k\subset k'$ is an algebraic extension, $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n] \subset k'[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is an integral extension of normal domains, so it satisfies [lying over, incomparability, going up, and going down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_up_and_going_down). This means that every prime ideal of $k'[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ lying over $I$ fits in to a chain of proper inclusions of prime ideals exactly of the same form. In particular, every irreducible component of $X'$ is of the exact same dimension as $X$.

To handle the case when $k\subset k'$ is not algebraic, it is enough to assume $k$ is algebraically closed. Each irreducible component of $X_{k'}$ lands in an irreducible component of $X_{\overline{k}}$, so we may work component-by-component on $X_{\overline{k}}$ and assume $X_{\overline{k}}$ is irreducible. Similarly, since taking the reduction preserves dimension, we may assume $X_{\overline{k}}$ is integral.

So assume $k$ is algebraically closed. We may also assume $k'$ is algebraically closed by our previous proof. Now the assumption that $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ is integral and affine implies that $X$ is geometrically reduced (see for instance Hartshorne exercise II.3.15 or Stacks [035X](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035X)), and so $X_{k'}=\operatorname{Spec} k'[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ is also integral. Now I claim that the transcendence degree of the field of fractions of $X$ and $X_{k'}$ over their base fields are equal: as $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ generate both field extensions, we note that $\operatorname{trdeg} k(X)/k \geq \operatorname{trdeg} k'(X_{k'})/k'$ by selecting a transcendence basis of $k(X)/k$ from the $x_i$ and the  fact that the algebraic dependence relations for the rest of the $x_i$ are polynomials with coefficients from $k$ and thus make sense as polynomials with coefficients from $k'$. On the other hand, if there is a polynomial relation between some of the $x_i$ in the transcendence basis over $k'$, this says that some system of polynomial equations has a solution over $k'$: by the nullstellensatz, this says that it must have a solution over $k$ as well, so the same relation must hold over $k$, showing the reverse inequality.

Comment: Why can we replace $k^\prime$ with its subfield? I don’t see why the minimal prime of $I$ actually lies in the subfield.